# Android, Bluetooth Headset, How to connect to Bluetooth Headset to read speech from its microphone?

Tags: android

I'm trying to connect to my Bluetooth Headset's HandsfreeAudioGateway/Handsfree/HeadsetAudioGateway/RFCOMM through a BluetoothSocket to get an InputStream so that I can read output of Bluetooth Headset's microphone. Actually I want use Bluetooth Headset's microphone as a wireless microphone in my application.

But the problem is whenever I'm calling

```
bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

bluetoothSocket.connect();
```

with following UUID( tried with all including those are commented)

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString(

        "00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
//          "00001203-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
//          "00000003-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
//          "00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" // Headset, connection fused
//          "0000111F-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
//          "0000111E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
//          "0000110B-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
            );
```

And each & every cases I'm getting

"java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed"

except in case of "00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" getting "java.io.IOException:connection fused"

Is there anybody who can help me out & correct me where I'm doing wrong?
Please help me out.